# Huddly camera wont send data to Azure IoT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect my Huddly to Azure, it seems to connect OK as seen in the below screenshot but does not seem to send any data.
[image: screenshot of camera connection in azure]

When I run index.js I get the below note.

> ** NB ** Host application must stream main in order to get detection events IQ Detector

The code I am working on can be found [here](https://github.com/Huddly/sdk/tree/master/examples/azure_iot).

Answer (score 0):

By default this code will only send detections if the must be streaming to a video application.

This can however be changed by the DOWS option so you get detections always.

`DOWS: false`

in the example you are referring to that is here 
https://github.com/Huddly/sdk/blob/3b462f73cdd51032b69619c99fc42625c677c8b0/examples/azure_iot/src/huddlyService.js#L49

```
 this.detector = await deviceManager.getDetector({
          DOWS: false,
          objectFilter: ['person']
        });
```